# SQLPLUS Query Trouble

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I've been using SQL*PLus lately and one of my tasks was to display the EmpCode, EmpName and PostCode of all Employees who satisfy the following: Every Item they sell has a price value above the average of all stock items

EDIT:
Hi Mark, I have written something similar to what you have suggested, but I am aware that the answers produced are wrong.

```
select E.EmpCode, E.EmpName, PostCode
from Employees E
LEFT OUTER JOIN Stocks ST
where Price >
(select AVG(Quantity) from Stocks
where E.EmpCode = ST.Empcde;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this

```
select distinct EmpCode, EmpName, PostCode
from Employees e
LEFT JOIN Stocks st On e.columnName= st.columnName
where Price >
(select AVG(Quantity) from Stocks
where e.EmpCode = st.EmpCode)
```

The syntax for a [LEFT JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp) is

```
t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
```

Also there's a missing parenthesis at the end